# algebras of infinite injective dimension

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Are there any connected graded Noetherian algebra of infinite injective dimension but has a balanced dualizing complex?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: All commutative connected graded noetherian algebras of finite Krull dimension have balanced dualizing complexes, by van den Bergh's criterion [they always have property $\chi$ and Grothendieck's theorem implies their local dimension is equal to their Krull dimension]. Pick any one that doesn't have finite injective dimension.

Comment: Any commutative connected graded noetherian algebra is a quotient of polynomial algebra in finite indeterminants, and so it has a balanced dualizing complex. However do you have any explicite such examples? Thank you very much!

Comment: $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorenstein_ring.